# how to update a data frame based on the condition in another data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frame and I want to update one column of `df_source` based on the condition in both data frames:

```
df_source = pd.Dataframe({'Sentiment':['neg', 'neg','pos'], 'text': ['hello ', '12where', 'here [null]'], 'pred': ['neu', 'neg', 'pos')})

df2 = pd.Dataframe({'Sentiment':['pos', 'neg','pos', 'neu'], 'text': ['hello ', '12 where I', 'hello g* ', 'here [null]'], 'pred': ['neu', 'neg', 'neu', 'neu')})
```

I want to update the column of `Sentiment` in `df_source` based on this condition: ***if the text in both data frame were exactly the same and the pred column was the same then replace the sentiment in df_source with the sentiment in df2***

So the output would be like this (as only one sample meets both condition "hello "):

```
Sentiment.    text.        pred
pos          hello         neu
neg          12where       neg
pos          here [null]   pos
```

What I have done:

```
df_source['Sentiment'] = df.where(((df['text']== df_source['text']) & (df['pred'] == dfs['pred'])) , df['Sentiment'])
```

It should work but this raises error (`ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`).

Comment: You only want 1 row left in `df_source` or you only want 1 row updated in `df_source`?

Comment: @HenryEcker Thanks for mentioning this. I forgot. I will update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First merge on the two columns and suffix.

```
df_source = df_source.merge(df2, how ='left', on =['text', 'pred'], suffixes=('_x', ''))
```

Replace the NaNs where there was no match using combine_first and then drop the extra merge column

```
df_source =df_source.assign(Sentiment= df_source['Sentiment'].combine_first(df_source.Sentiment_x) ).drop('Sentiment_x',1)

 

          text pred Sentiment
0       hello   neu       pos
1      12where  neg       neg
2  here [null]  pos       pos
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! a little difficult to understand what's going onion the second line. bur willl look at the documentation for the`combine_first` and hopefully will get it. thanks again.

Comment: I encourage you to. Thats how we learn. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html